# How do you translate "kill switch" (IT stealth technology context)?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, informatique

> The Uber Files also show that the company’s use of stealth technology
> to thwart government investigations was far more expansive than
> previously reported. Company executives activated a so-called **kill
> switch** to cut access to company servers and prevent authorities from
> seizing evidence during raids on Uber offices in at least six
> countries, according to the leaked documents.
>
> [ [*How Uber won access to world leaders, deceived investigators and
> exploited violence against its drivers in battle for global
> dominance*](https://www.icij.org/investigations/uber-files/uber-global-rise-lobbying-violence-technology/), ICIJ ]

It feels to me like [*arrêt d'urgence*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arr%C3%AAt_d%27urgence_(automatique)) is somewhat off or inadequate. So how should *kill switch* be translated in this IT context?

> Les dirigeants de l'entreprise ont activé un(e) soi-disant [kill
> switch] afin de couper l'accès aux serveurs de l'entreprise [...]

Answer (score 5):

Je vais produire une trouvaille sur *Termium* dans le domaine des circuits électriques et des dispositifs de sécurité pour voir si on aime ça :

> [*coupe-circuit*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=kill%20switch&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) : Appareil qui interrompt un circuit électrique par la fusion d'un de ses éléments, lorsque le courant est trop important, en cas de court-circuit, etc.

Answer (score 4):

La traduction ***arrêt d'urgence*** me paraît convenable. Elle correspond bien à l'image qu'on se fait du gros bouton rouge présent dans les systèmes où un individu non qualifié peut être amené à interrompre un équipement en cas de danger imminent (escalator, machine outil, rame de métro, etc.)

Si on veut clarifier le fait qu'il ne s'agit pas d'éteindre les ordinateurs locaux mais de les isoler, on peut éventuellement parler, par exemple, de *bouton de **déconnexion d'urgence***, *d'**isolation réseau d'urgence*** ou *de **mise hors-réseau immédiate***.

Answer (score 2):

Selon les organes de presse, la traduction hésite entre **coupe-circuit** (par  exemple sur [France Info](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/politique/affaire/uber-files/activez-le-kill-switch-quand-uber-neutralisait-ses-ordinateurs-a-distance-pour-bloquer-les-perquisitions_5248585.html)) et **arrêt d'urgence** (par exemple dans [Le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/pixels/article/2022/07/11/uber-files-comment-uber-a-tente-d-entraver-les-enquetes-et-les-perquisitions-dans-ses-locaux-avec-la-technique-du-kill-switch_6134353_4408996.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I think I would translate in with « bouton d’autodestruction » or, more implicitly, « bouton rouge ».

Comment: Note AFAIK the data is not impacted but merely the ability to retrieve it from a station/terminal. In that context do you consider "destruction" not too far-fetched?

Comment: Yes, it probably is too far-fetched.

Comment: Nevertheless, it should prove useful if that were the case.

Answer (score -1):

Le terme « *procédure d'avortement* » semble assez conforme à l'idée d'arrêter un processus en cours et de le rendre nul.  Le terme « *logiciel d'avortement* » est certainement plus spécifique puisqu'il s'agit sans aucun doute d'un programme, et il serait à mon avis préférable.

> (Wiktionnaire) (Par extension) (Reproduction) Échec d’un développement quelconque sans rapport avec la procréation.
>
> - L'avortement du projet a eu lieu avant l’obtention des premiers résultats.

Comment: On peut connaitre la raison de ce vote négatif ? Le mot « avortement » est parfaitement bien défini dans ce contexte.

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 Bien sûr, c'est une définition par extension, un sens figuré, mais combien sont les sens ainsi définis qiui prennent dans la langue une signification toute particulière et dont le terme est finalement  irremplaçable, ou tout au moins parait l'être… De plus n'avons nous pas là l'occasion d'une assimilation du processus similaire de l'anglais qui permet à la fois la consolidation de l'idée dans le français et un moyen de traduction direct ? Non, je pense que le processus de recherche  (1/2)

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 dans le système,  qui à un certain point est arrêté (en quelque sorte rendu sans suite) est un processus d'avortement.  De plus, il n'est question d'aucune urgence; la « sub-routine » d'arrêt de la continuation est enclenchée ou elle ne l'est pas. (2/2)

Comment: _Fair enough_, reste que ça surprend.

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 Eh oui! La vie surprend!

Comment: @LPH pas downvoté, mais il me semble que faire avorter signifie arrêter avant son terme un processus en cours qui a un début et une fin. Or ici, il s'agit plus de "couper les ponts" entre deux réseaux, deux entités qui ont une existence continue.